# How does one find real Host when using Cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

In what seems to be a very weird choice, Cloudfront sets the Host header to the origin server host that you specify when forwarding a request.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html

Why is this? More importantly, when using wildcard subdomains, how do I know which subdomain the request is from, when they all forward to the same origin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good news- [cloudfront supports host header forwarding now](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/06/26/amazon-cloudfront-device-detection-geo-targeting-host-header-cors/). It's listed very deep in [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#request-custom-headers-behavior):

```
Host [header]: CloudFront sets the value to the domain name of the origin that is associated with the requested object.
```

Presumably, all you need to do is ensure header forwarding is enabled in the Default Cache Behavior Settings:

[image: header forwarding configuration in cloudfront]

Comment: The second link, to documentation, does not say that you can forward the Host header, but that it will be set to the origin domain name?

Comment: This does not work if your custom origin is a CloudFront origin (API Gateway endpoint)

Comment: The OP stated that cloudfront sets the header to the origin host and the documentation linked says exactly the same thing. It's not helping to answer the question.

Comment: I have confirmed that this method works. But you need set the cname domain different to origin host, and the origin host have dns A/AAAA record point the the origin server. with the Whitelist Headers have the Host header, the cloudfront will use the origin server ip and cname domain in the host to assign the origin server. You need a valid tls certification for the cname domain in the origin server if you are using https protocol to access the origin server.(I have got one by letsencrypt dns verify method.)

Comment: yep.  however it seems not working with s3